# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I am getting following error in Samsung note 2 in 4.4.2 , version. I also have tried with HTC One X+ 4.2.2. I think its pre-lollipop. Cause its working fine on Lollipop.  any guess?

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.49-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.49-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile project(':library')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:5.0.6'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile project(':dropboxChooserSDK')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.20.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev173-1.20.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.20.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.20.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-gson-1.20.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Exception I am getting.

```
 26927-26927/com.example.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder', referenced from method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.initializePanelMenu
06-09 21:12:24.014  26927-26927/com.example.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder', referenced from method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu
06-09 21:12:24.014  26927-26927/com.example.app E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder', referenced from method android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onPreparePanel
06-09 21:12:24.019  26927-26927/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 26927
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompat
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.installViewFactory(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:812)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
            at com.example.app.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:37)
            at com.example.app.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:29)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: No need to declare all the individual jars since you already have `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`

Comment: @tibo this didnt solve anything :-(

Comment: yeah, that was just for clean up :)

Comment: @tibo thanks. can you help me with this error?

Comment: Any luck here @Manoj?

Comment: It seems there's some talk about it here, but I've verified the support lib used and couldn't spot any extra JARs used: https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/#comment-1990075081

Comment: @Tom Redeman I have tried this too. I was able to fix this with proguard edit. But that comes with price too. You have to be careful if you are using gson ... You have to add that too in proguard . but yeah  I am able to get this sorted

Comment: Hmm so it works when using Proguard? Interesting. Thanks @manoj :)

Comment: Confirmed it's working for me with Proguard/Dexguard. So strange.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem (app will crashed in all devices <= Android 4.4, but worked fine when Android >= 5.0) with the following `build.gradle` setting:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aams.going"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev141-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.4'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.6.0'
}
```

## Problem

It is caused by `multiDexEnabled true` with Google Play services API and google-api in gradle.

## Solution

I solved this problem by removing `multiDexEnabled true` and specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs my app uses.

- Removing `multiDexEnabled true`.
- Use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0'` instead of `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`

Here is my final and worked `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aams.going"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev141-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:1.4'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.6.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable multidex could rusult in a runtime exeption  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: then, Acorde to https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup : If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them.

Example:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
compile  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0'
compile  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.1.0'
```

In the link you can find a list of Apis. If you are no using google play services, then apply the same principle to your dependencies.