# Android App Error (4.2-4.4) - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

my google play developer console displays me this crash. But I do not know why the app crashes. Please help me. Thanks

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.zzaR(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzn.zziJ(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5067)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4592)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!-- Splash screen -->
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Slider"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HilfeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hilfe"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
</application>
```

This is my manifest. There arent any errors. If this is helpful. Also the ad isn't displayed correctly. Is this from the ads?

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: @MiladYarmohammadi -- Posted

Comment: which activity raises exception?

Comment: Main I think  @MiladYarmohammadi

Comment: is your sdk updated?

Comment: Have you set `multidex` in gradle file ?

Comment: @MiladYarmohammadi yes

Comment: Remove `google-paly-service` and add the spceific one which you require .see this it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736954/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-view-layoutinflatercompat